# Add prebuilt apk into LineageOS

Tags: android-source, lineageos

I'm trying to add a .apk to LineageOS 20.
Currently I did this:

**build/target/product/handheld_product.mk**:

```
...
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    Chromium \
...
```

I put the apk into packages/apps/Chromium/ as app-release.apk

**packages/apps/Chromium/android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := Chromium
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app-release.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

# LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE = true
# LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)
# LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2  Launcher3

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX :=  $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: If you sure that handheld_product.mk is the device Makefile and the Android.mk has the "A" in uppercase, the setup seems ok, what is the log output? There are any error?

Here one example:
https://github.com/snappautomotive/firmware-vendor_snappautomotive_packages_maps